# Detect incoming call to skype for business client and take action(accept, reject) in a website(UCWA / Skype Web SDK)

Tags: voip, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

[Solution today]

We have a working solution today where we have a widget installed on the users computer which uses the "Lync Client SDK" to intercept incoming calls and lookup information automatically and then lets the user reject/accept the call from the widget.

We are now wondering if the following scenario is possible using "UCWA" or the even simpler wrapper for it the "Skype Web SDK" (or any other alternative if better)

- User has Skype for business installed on computer (Connected to Skype for Business 2015 Server - On premise)
- User is using a website (We have full control over the website)

[Scenario]

When a customer makes a call to this users Skype for business(client) the call should be intercepted(somehow) and the website should be notified/get data about the number calling so lookups can be done on the website where the client can then make a decision to either reject/accept the call from the website. Imagine the website has an widget for this sole purpose.

I have been trying to find information on various sites but can only find information about simpler scenarious presence and instant messaging regarding UCWA and Skype Web SDK.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt124990.aspx

https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/

[Question]

Is this scenario even possible(at this date or will this functionality be included later down the road)? or can anybody with knowledge in this area point me in the right direction or share similar scenarios and how you handled it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider 'unediting' your answer from the original post, and supplying the content as an answer. It is OK to answer own questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UCWA could be used only being authenticated - so, user credentials are necessary. Further on, an UCWA client [Event Channel](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/GettingStarted-Events) should be created (which is a "long polling" GET request to the SfB server). When a call arrives, a notification will be received on this event channel and further actions based on received data will be possible.

A trusted application, acting on behalf of other users could be created using the [UCMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454984%28v=office.16%29.aspx)